# Create and read tree data structure from json string dynamically

Tags: java, json, lucene, jettison

I'm trying to develop a dynamic query builder for days. But I'm having a problem with building it.

What I'm reviving is a json like this.

```
{"category":"Case Law","query":{"AND":{"Year":{"having":"","exact":"","any":"","none":""},"AND":{"Report":{"having":"","exact":"","any":"","none":""},"Citation":{"having":"","exact":"","any":"","none":""}}}}}
```

Here is it in much readable way

```
Array
(
    [category] => Case Law
    [query] => Array
        (
            [OR] => Array
                (
                    [Year] => Array
                        (
                            [having] => some
                            [exact] => values
                            [any] => might
                            [none] => have
                        )

                    [AND] => Array
                        (
                            [Report] => Array
                                (
                                    [having] => 
                                    [exact] => 
                                    [any] => 
                                    [none] => 
                                )

                            [Citation] => Array
                                (
                                    [having] => 
                                    [exact] => 
                                    [any] => 
                                    [none] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

- this json can change according to the user inputs(can have more depth
  or less).
- what I'm trying to do is create a search query for apache
  lucene...(for the moment lets assume that leaf values are just
  strings.)

It **must be** something like this(What I need)

> (Year:another values OR (Report:some valeus AND Citation:some valeues))

I tried with Jettison library and used DefaultMutableTreeNode to create the tree structure  . But it didn't work as I expected.Then i tried whit recursive functions and it also didn't worked

I want to is it possible to create this kind of thing. If yes how to do.

Your attempt is highly appreciated! 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON String for you query

Ok. This is what i tried.

(Year:another values OR (Report:some valeus AND Citation:some valeues AND Field: another))

should be something like :

```
String json = 
{"lhs":{"lhs":{"lhs":{"lhs":"Field","rhs":"Value","operator":"EQUAL_TO"},"rhs":{"lhs":"Citation","rhs":"Citation","operator":"EQUAL_TO"},"operator":"AND"},"rhs":{"lhs":"Report","rhs":"Report1","operator":"EQUAL_TO"},"operator":"AND"},"rhs":{"lhs":"Year","rhs":"2001","operator":"EQUAL_TO"},"operator":"OR"}
```

if The MYOperator enum is :

```
public enum MyOperator {

    AND,
    OR,
    EQUAL_TO {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ":";
    }
},
    IN

}
```

and AtomicOperation Is

```
public class AtomicOperation {


     Object lhs;
     Object rhs;
     MyOperator operator;

     AtomicOperation(Object lhs,MyOperator operator, Object rhs) {
         this.lhs = lhs;
         this.rhs = rhs;
         this.operator = operator;
     }

    public Object getLhs() {
        return lhs;
    }
    public void setLhs(Object lhs) {
        this.lhs = lhs;
    }
    public Object getRhs() {
        return rhs;
    }
    public void setRhs(Object rhs) {
        this.rhs = rhs;
    }
    public MyOperator getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }
    public void setOperator(MyOperator operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

     @Override
public String toString() {
        return "(" + lhs.toString() + " " + operator.toString() + " " + rhs.toString() + ")"; 
}

}
```

Then You can Build the necessary AtomicOperation Object using the below code

```
AtomicOperation _r = deriveFromJSON(ConvertJsonToObject.getFromJSON(json,AtomicOperation.class));
```

Below is the complete ConvertJsonToObject class

```
public class ConvertJsonToObject {

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    public static final <T> T getFromJSON(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, clazz);
    }

    public static final <T> String toJSON(T clazz) {
        return gson.toJson(clazz);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey try now...i have written proper toString() method for AtomicOperation

Comment: also modify toString method of EQUAL_TO in the enum MyOperator

Comment: with that what I'm getting is "({lhs={lhs={lhs=Field, rhs=Value, operator=EQUAL_TO}, rhs={lhs=Citation, rhs=Citation, operator=EQUAL_TO}, operator=AND}, rhs={lhs=Report, rhs=Report1, operator=EQUAL_TO}, operator=AND} OR {lhs=Year, rhs=2001, operator=EQUAL_TO})"

I think it's because AtomicOperation to string get executed only one time

Comment: hey i have edited the code...copy the entire edited code with updated toString method then finally call _r.toString() and you will get ((((Field : Value) AND (Citation : Citation)) AND (Report : Report1)) OR (Year : 2001)) as output.

Comment: ConvertJsonToObject.getFromJSON(json, AtomicOperation.class) gives "({lhs={lhs={lhs=Field, rhs=Value, operator=EQUAL_TO}, rhs={lhs=Citation, rhs=Citation, operator=EQUAL_TO}, operator=AND}, rhs={lhs=Report, rhs=Report1, operator=EQUAL_TO}, operator=AND} OR {lhs=Year, rhs=2001, operator=EQUAL_TO})" and it never execute "if (operation.getLhs().getClass().equals(LinkedHashMap.class)) " part. At the end produce same output!! The enum should be in the main class right ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14788/discussion-between-rj45-and-byter)

Answer (score 2):

Ok Now the requirement is clear and here is the solution

define your operations

```
enum MyOperator {

  AND,
  OR

}
```

Write a class to hold you atomic operaton

```
class AtomicOperation {

   Object lhs;
   Object rhs;
   MyOperator operator;

}
```

Now if You want something like
(Year:another values OR (Report:some valeus AND Citation:some valeues))

your JSON should look like :

```
String jsonString = {{Year:['2001','2002']} OR {{Report:['Report1']} AND {Citation:['Citation1']}}}
```

So First Cast this JSON to AtominOperation class
using the code

```
ConvertJsonToObject.getFromJSON(jsonString,AtominOperation.class);

GSON will cast it to a Simple AtominOperation Object with operation "OR"
and lhs,rhs as 2 LinkedHashMaps (Default behaviour of GSON)

Now use the below method to get the proper AtomicOperation Object from the
above AtomicOperation Object.

public static AtomicOperation deriveFromJSON(AtomicOperation operation) {

        if (operation.getLhs().getClass().equals(LinkedHashMap.class)) {
            AtomicOperation leftOperation = deriveFromJSON(ConvertJsonToObject
                    .getFromJSON(ConvertJsonToObject.toJSON(operation.getLhs()),
                            AtomicOperation.class));
            AtomicOperation rightOperation = deriveFromJSON(ConvertJsonToObject
                    .getFromJSON(ConvertJsonToObject.toJSON(operation.getRhs()),
                            AtomicOperation.class));
            return new AtomicOperation(leftOperation, operation.getOperator(),
                    rightOperation);
        }
        return operation;

    }
```

The Final AtomicOperation Object would be what u want. :)

Comment: I have small question what if user send something like this 
(Year:another values OR (Report:some valeus AND Citation:some valeues AND Field: another)) . 
Then the AtomicOperation class is not valid right ?

Comment: It Still is. It will look like
{{Year:['2001','2002']} OR {{Report:['Report1']} AND {Citation:['Citation1']} AND {Field:another}}}

Actually Speaking, you need more operators like EQUAL_TO , IN so that you can write like this

{Year IN [values] OR {{Report IN [values]} AND {Citation IN [values]} AND {Field EQUAL_TO "value"}}}

Comment: Hey I'tried with that... But I'm getting an error NullPointerException at deriveFromJSON() first line. If you have written the code could you please post whole code as a answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Something like Google Gson

class ConvertJsonToObject {

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    public static final <T> T getFromJSON(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, clazz);
    }

}

String jsonString = "{"category":"Case Law","query":{"AND":{"Year the case was instituted":{"having":"","exact":"","any":"","none":""},"AND":{"Report":{"having":"","exact":"","any":"","none":""},"Citation":{"having":"","exact":"","any":"","none":""}}}}}
"

Now you can use ConvertJsonToObject.getFromJSON(jsonString,Map.class);
```

Comment: But how to create some thing like (Year:another values OR (Report:some valeus AND Citation:some valeues))